# Python - Extend Class used by another Class in a Package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a package which defines a couple of classes (A & B). I want to extend class A in my `main.py` to include `var_d`. I have tried the following:

File: my_package.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_a = 'var_a'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_b = A()
        self.var_c = A()
```

File: main.py

```
from my_package import *

a = B()
a.var_b.var_d = 'extending class A to have this new var'
```

This doesn't work. What's an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "setattr"

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_a = 'var_a'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_b = A()
        self.var_c = A()
a = B()
setattr(a.var_b, 'var_d', 1)
```

leads to

```
print(a.var_b.var_d)
>> 1
```

Comment: This works but is it possible to do it such that class A is extended? So that `a.var_c.var_d` is also set?

Comment: Ah you ment something like "static variables". You can use static variables with the property keyword. But class A have to know about the property during initialization. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27568860/8386455 is great to learn about static variables

Answer (score 0):

In your `class A`, the `self.var_a` is not assigned value. The variables in python exist automatically in the first scope where they're assigned. In your current code, `self.var_a` was not assigned. If you do `self.var_a = ''` for example, it should be working.

update:I may get confused about what you are asking. Your error code complains about 'var_a', that what my answer for.

Comment: Apologies. Badly formulated question! I have updated it and removed the misleading error.